# Running a shell script from yaml file in dataproc template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to run a shell script as a job through yaml file using dataproc workflow template.If yes, how can we do that.

I've worked on workflow templates but they are hadoop and spark jobs,but i'm not sure how to run the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do it but there is a workaround: add a pig job step with `-e=sh myscript.sh`. You would have to stage the file on the cluster via an init action.

Alternatively, you could create a python script that shells out to the bash script. Advantage of doing this is a `pyspark` job will take care of downloading the script for you via `--files` argument.

Comment: when i've tried to run the shell script as pig job,it showing that i've add 3 jars to /usr/lib/hive/-- but when i'm trying to add jars...it is showing that permission is denied.Is this the correct way?

Comment: That's unexpected. Could you share dataproc image version you used?